# How to do a phone call as an Action for the Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to develop a Google Assistant App, that would call an end user for a status update.

In this case, how do I do a phone call as an Action for the Assistant?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no API for calling even though the Home device is quite capable of doing it. Now that the Assistant can deep link into an Android "activity", you could have a companion mobile app make the call for mobile users. That doesn't help your users with iPhones. A big hack would have you deliver a rich response with a "basic card" that has a button with the a link to a URL using the "tel:" scheme.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on "basic card" hack ?

Comment: An Action can return a basic card which includes a button which has a hyperlink to a page on the web. On that page you can have a hyperlink which uses the "tel": scheme (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3966). If the user taps that link then the dialer should be launched on Android at least. FWIW, I haven't tried this recently on iOS or the desktop.